# How to disable Java in the browser for all users?

Tags: java, configuration, administrator

After reading [this news](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/ICYMI+Widespread+Unserialize+Vulnerability+in+Java/20353/) I decided that I would disable Java in my browser, so I opened up the `Java Control Panel` and went to the `Security` tab:

[image]

However after unticking `Enable Java content in the browser` I was met with this response:

[image]

So the first thing I tried was to launch the `Java Control Panel` as I usually do except for executing the command with `sudo`:

```
sudo ControlPanel
```

However this was the response:

```
sudo: ControlPanel: command not found
```

So how do I disable Java in the browser globally then? How do I do it as an "Administrator" if not through `sudo`?

**Additional Information:**

I downloaded Java by downloading the JDK from the Oracle website and then unzipped it in my `~` directory, and I also set this up in my `.bashrc` file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/marvin/jdk1.8.0_66
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

**Package Information:**

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the ControlPanel as an Administrator by:

```
sudo /home/marvin/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/ControlPanel
```

But the right way to disable java in a browser is to disable java plugin in a browser itself.

See [THIS LINK](http://java.com/en/download/help/disable_browser.xml)

Comment: The output of that command is: `sudo: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/ControlPanel: command not found`.

Comment: How did you install java?

Comment: I have updated my question with additional information.

Comment: So the path is different.

Comment: And it is not a good idea to install executables to home. Anyway just disable the plugin in your browser.

Comment: I want to disable it globally though, so disabling it just in my browser won't do the trick. What is the correct path then? And why is it not a good idea to have executables in your home area?

Comment: I added the path for your java install. Executable files in home are unsafe. Install java e.g. to `/opt`.

Comment: And you export path only for the current user.

Comment: Ok, what exactly is the `/opt` directory? And what about if I just made the JDK directory and all files and sub-directories owned by root?

Comment: `/opt` is for installing this kind of things. And the java files SHOULD be owned by root.

Comment: Also, I am unable to find a plug-in in my browser that has anything to do with Java.

Comment: It is probably not installed. And java is already disabled in your browser. You'd better install java from [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). It will be installed correctly and will get updates.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your advice, I am now installing it through the PPA, however I also use NetBeans IDE which installs its installation folder in `~`, should I also have this installed in somewhere like `/opt` or is it ok?

Comment: All binaries should be owned by root anyway.

Comment: By the way, why exactly is it a bad idea to have executable files and binaries owned by oneself in one's home directory?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already been answered, but in my case I can easily open the ControlPanel as root using the following command. I am writing this in case it helps somebody else:

> sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djavaplugin.user.profile= -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/deploy.jar com.sun.deploy.panel.ControlPanel

**OR:**

> gksu /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djavaplugin.user.profile= -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/deploy.jar com.sun.deploy.panel.ControlPanel